# CryptUnprotectData function returning encrypted value

Tags: c++, winapi

I have been trying to wrap my head around how to use the `CryptUnprotectData` function in c++, but I can seem to get it correct. As of now, the function doesn't seem to be doing anything (the value returned is the value given. When I use `GetLastError()`, I get an error code of 87 (invalid parameter).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

string data = ("data I want to decode");
cout << "Encrypted data: " << data << endl;

DATA_BLOB DataOut;

BYTE* pbDataOutput = (BYTE*)data.data();
DataOut.pbData = pbDataOutput;
DataOut.cbData = strlen((char*)pbDataOutput);

DATA_BLOB DataVerify;
LPWSTR pDescrOut =  NULL;


if (CryptUnprotectData(&DataOut, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,0,&DataVerify)){
     cout << "decrypted data: " << DataVerify.pbData << endl;
     LocalFree(DataVerify.pbData);
}

else{
    cout << "Decryption error: ";
    cout << GetLastError() << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

I have tried copying the code from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program-using-cryptprotectdata) and whittling it down until it just decrypts a string, but I get the same error.

Comment: [`CryptUnprotectData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptunprotectdata) doesn't return a value of `HRESULT`. It returns a value of type `BOOL`. Regardless, return values must not be ignored.

Comment: Where and how does `"(data I want to decode)"` come from? Are you sure it was generated by a previous call to `CryptProtectData` by the same user on the same machine? In any case, `DataBytes.cbData = strlen((char*)pbDataOutput) + 1;` is likely wrong. The binary encoded data may and likely does contain zero bytes; and if by chance it does not, you shouldn't include the terminating NUL character either.

Comment: Alright, I've implemented your corrections but it I'm still getting error code 87 :/

Comment: We cannot see your code, nor have you explained where your input data is coming from.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'll update the code when I can. As for your other point, I am sure it is coming from another call to the function. It is an encrypted key inside the chrome "local state" json file. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: The call to `GetLastError` returns a meaningless value at the point you are calling it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really follow, could you elaborate a bit further on that? Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: `CryptUnprotectData` isn't documented to set the calling thread's last error code. If it did, you'd have to call `GetLastError` *immediately* after you have established the conditions under which it returns a meaningful value, with absolutely no code in between.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you should create a session key to perform encryption, and then use the CryptUnprotectData function to decrypt the data.